# Unexpected behavior of simple VHDL circuit

Tags: vhdl, delay, behavior

What the cause of different delays of signals Q_VLD1 and Q_VLD2 in simulator?
[Result of simulation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYLrJ.jpg) Is it expected behaviour of simulator or not?

I use Xilinx Isim. 
There is the code and testbench for it:

```
entity assign_test is
    port(CLK   : in  STD_LOGIC;
         D_VLD : in  STD_LOGIC;
         Q_VLD1 : out STD_LOGIC;
         Q_VLD2 : out STD_LOGIC
    );
end assign_test;

architecture Behavioral of assign_test is
    signal D_VLD_i : std_logic;
    signal d_vld_dly1 : std_logic;
    signal d_vld_dly2 : std_logic;
begin
    D_VLD_i <= D_VLD;

    process (clk) is
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            d_vld_dly1 <= D_VLD;
            d_vld_dly2 <= D_VLD_i;
        end if;
    end process ;

    Q_VLD1 <= d_vld_dly1;
    Q_VLD2 <= d_vld_dly2;
end Behavioral;


ENTITY tb_assign_test IS
END tb_assign_test;
ARCHITECTURE behavior OF tb_assign_test IS 

    COMPONENT assign_test
    PORT(
         CLK : IN  std_logic;
         D_VLD : IN  std_logic;
         Q_VLD1 : OUT  std_logic;
         Q_VLD2 : OUT  std_logic
        );
    END COMPONENT;

   --Inputs
   signal CLK : std_logic := '0';
   signal D_VLD : std_logic := '0';
    --Outputs
   signal Q_VLD1 : std_logic;
   signal Q_VLD2 : std_logic;
   constant CLK_period : time := 10 ns;

BEGIN 
   uut: assign_test PORT MAP (
          CLK => CLK,
          D_VLD => D_VLD,
          Q_VLD1 => Q_VLD1,
          Q_VLD2 => Q_VLD2
        );

   CLK_process :process
   begin
        CLK <= '0';
        wait for CLK_period/2;
        CLK <= '1';
        wait for CLK_period/2;
   end process;

   stim_proc: process
   begin        
      wait for 100 ns;  
      wait for 5 ns;    
      wait for CLK_period*10;
      D_VLD <= '1';
      wait for CLK_period*3;
      D_VLD <= '0';
      wait;
   end process;
END;
```

Comment: Dear downvoter, would be great if you left a comment with reason for giving a downvote, so the question can be improved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So if you look at the internal signals in the `assign_test` module, based on simulation time only, it may look as in figure below (`d_vld_dly*` is before assign to `Q_VLD*`).

[image]

But the figure is misleading, since that figure does not show the [VHDL concept of delta delay](http://insights.sigasi.com/opinion/jan/vhdls-crown-jewel.html).  If the waveform is expanded to show delta delays (using ModelSim in this case), it looks like below.

[image]

So this reveals that the `D_VLD_i <= D_VLD;` in the `assign_test` actually delays the `D_VLD_i` a delta delay, whereby the new value is not seen at the clock until next rising clock edge.

The reason for this problem, is that the test bench does not generate input data as a **cause** of the clock, which would make data one delta delay after the clock, but independently and at the same simulation time **and** same delta delay as the clock.

The test bench can be updated to generate data as a **cause** of the clock, if wait for clock is changed from:

```
wait for CLK_period*10;
```

to:

```
for i in 1 to 10 loop
  wait until rising_edge(CLK);
end loop;
```

which will then give a waveform as:

[image]

So based on this, a rule for good test bench design is to generate stimuli the same way as generating data in synthesized modules, so the stimuli from the test bench is like data between modules in general, in order to get expected and reliable and test bench behavior.